# How to customize mavericks' mac osx server apache configuration?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-mavericks

I have installed Mac OSX Mavericks Server and I would like to add some features to the Apache Server (gitolite, redmine, etc.) I've started with updating the `httpd_server_app.conf` file in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2` but unfortunately it has been overwritten by the server to its default. Maybe because I've updated something in the UI, or an update occurred... Anyway, I would like to know how can I update the configuration file in a permanent and persistent way, and still benefit the OSX Server UI and/or updates...

I've probably missed the big : "Put your own things here:" label...

PS: By the way, I wish to modify some of the current configuration, not only adding things...

Answer (score 7):

In the Mavericks Server, setup a new site. Mavericks will set this up as virtualhost under `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites`. The conf file is named by IP, port, and host. You can edit this file and it will not be overwritten... to an extent. I've added directory permissions, wsgiAlias paths, daemon processes, and necessary tools for basic django install.

A caveat being that I've not tried to update the host name, port, or IP, from Server app, after editing the conf. This may generate some entirely new conf from a default template - unsure.

Server app will also provide you with a small permissions battle. Future settings updates via Server app tend to override your own write permissions. Server updates from Apple may also move your existing conf files to a *previous* directory.

I am sure there are long term solutions for these problems. But I suck at permissions.

Comment: I have manually edited the files in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites` and I can attest to the fact that you will probably break permissions from editing/adding new sites via this method. If you decide to manually edit your config, be prepared to have to deal with the possibility of manually editing the files forever (until you fix the permissions at least, which I still haven't quite figured out yet).

Comment: Looks like a Software Update came through and moved my conf hacks to *apache2.previous*.

Comment: mine were moved to _apache2.sites-previous-unusable_?!? ouch!

Answer (score 2):

i know this is an old question, but in Yosemite (assuming the same in Mavericks and earlier) in /library/server/web/config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf it references:

IncludeOptional /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/*.conf

I have created a custom new .conf file there /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/other/custom.conf with the directives I needed and can confirm that they are picked up and used.

I would think that this folder isn't touched when doing a server upgrade as well as the IncludeOptional line mentioned above. Now you don't have to touch any of the server.app conf files and worry about permissions, etc. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The apache config stuff on my mbp is located in

```
/private/etc/apache2
```

that includes `httpd.conf`

Comment: Unfortunately this config file is used on not-server config. As soon as you install OSX Server the new config files are in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2`

Comment: Aha look at http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, I do not want to start another Apache server, as I am using the one configured with Mac OSX Server (https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-server/id714547929?mt=12) which configuration is located in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2`

Comment: Here what is said:
`# When Server App is installed, this file is used instead of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
`# At Server.app promotion time this file is copied to `
`# /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf and Apache's launchd.plist is `
`# modified to use it as the main config file.`

Answer (score 0):

The files for configuration now live in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2
The /etc/apache2/ directory seems to be pretty much a dummy - during configuration only two files were touched there.